# case insensitive preg replace on special chars/Umlaute

Tags: php, preg-replace, match, case-insensitive

This works:

```
echo preg_replace("/TesT/i","<b>FOUND</b>","TEST"); // works as expected prints FOUND
```

Why does this below not work? In my project I want to highlight a search result no matter of the case/writing of the search input

```
echo preg_replace("/üöÄ/i","<b>FOUND</b>","ÜÖÄ"); // does NOT work as expected prints ÜÖÄ
```

I tried the below as well which also does not work:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
mb_regex_encoding("UTF-8");
mb_ereg_replace("/üöÄ/i","<b>FOUND</b>","ÜÖÄ");
```

UPDATE:
As far as I know I made sure everything on my page, the scripts, the connections are all UTF-8

Comment: The problem is not one of character sets, but of collation. Collation is the thing that tells your code "e and E are the same". You don't seem to have the right collation set, because it's missing "ü and Ü are the same".

Comment: Most painless solution: use it like `/[üÜ][öÖ][Ää]/` - second option would be dealing with locales

Comment: But how would that work in a sentence like User-Input:"äpfel muß BrÜcken"......Database-Value:"äpfel muß brücken"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You additionally need to pass the `u` option for `utf8` support.

This will work:

```
echo preg_replace("/üöÄ/iu","<b>FOUND</b>","ÜÖÄ");
```

You can find the list of available options here: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php